# Type '{ tabs: TabsProps[] | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TabsProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, ant-design-pro

I'm creating a reusable tab view component using the latest ant design version. do I need to add Tabpane separately or does the latest ant design version have it with 'Tabs'?

**my code :**

```
import { Tabs } from "antd";
import type { TabsProps} from 'antd';

interface Props {
    defaultActiveKey?: string | undefined;   
    onChange?:() => void;    
    tabs?: TabsProps [] | undefined;
}

export default function TabView({onChange, defaultActiveKey, tabs}: Props) {

    return (
        <Tabs 
          onChange={onChange}
          defaultActiveKey={defaultActiveKey}
>         tabs={tabs}
        />    
    )
}
```

**Error:**

[image]

while adding tabs={tabs} I'm getting this type of error. I need to add TabItemType to tabs?: in props. any help to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this example](https://ant.design/components/tabs#examples) from antd it looks like there are 2 errors in your example. The Tabs component takes `items` props instead of `tabs`. More importantly `tabs` prop should be typed as `TabsProps["items"]`.

Now it works

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Tabs } from "antd";
import type { TabsProps} from 'antd';

interface Props {
    defaultActiveKey?: string | undefined;   
    onChange?:() => void;    
    tabs?: TabsProps['items'];
}

export default function TabView({onChange, defaultActiveKey, tabs}: Props) {

    return (
        <Tabs 
          onChange={onChange}
          defaultActiveKey={defaultActiveKey}
          items={tabs}
        />    
    )
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoUSWOAbzgBUUAjAZzgF85tc4AiFADsYAEz4Uq0eDACeYJHUYtWABRxhWXHnnxDRZcpWFIomdArUQNdcnDtwRSMwFcANjACCGYADckAaSQZAH4ALjhWGChgQQBzOAAfOGdBR0wYpBFSe1t7CEEAYQALIVikMIAKAEo4AF4APjgfCGAs+zhcuxhlMKU2Sw0AbXxgGCQQVnwAXQoOQyQAD2p4NJQ3LBTvfL6ANWAkAHcK2nzi0qQAGgcnNfcvGF8AoKvutg5wgdYa2kN2ohhnFBBHAKp12nAADxMNgdcHg04lOJIWonQqIspzOHtVbre6PQIyFE4u7ePwEzFYuCjcasFGvTRg9oAekaOXaVXIcyAA)